# In WordPress blog, don't want to print CATEGORY: as heading

Tags: wordpress

**(image for reference) dont want to print the rounded area in image**

[image]

I have a WordPress blog and it has two categories but when open the category it shows Category: category name as the heading but I want to print only category name as a heading

Comment: I believe https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/remove-category-tag-author-from-the-archive-title should have your question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to ..\wp-content\themes\Your theme name and you will find archive.php file, open archive.php in an editor and find Category, just remove 'Category:'.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Administration > Appearance > Editor and you can find category.php , open the file and find the Word  "Category:" remove it and save the file. After that check the output.

Comment: i have installed Manta theme, in the editor, i am not getting category.php page

Comment: Ok ,Can you give me the list of files you have ?

Comment: Templates
404 Template
(404.php),
Comments
(comments.php),
Theme Footer
(footer.php),
Theme Functions
(functions.php),
Theme Header
(header.php),
Image Attachment Template
(image.php),
defaults.php
(inc/defaults.php),
display.php
(inc/display.php),
filters.php
(inc/filters.php),
Main Index Template
(index.php),
Search Form
(searchform.php),
Sidebar
(sidebar.php),
Styles
Stylesheet
(style.css),

Comment: check inside the functions.php if you found the word delete one by one and check in the output.  Note :Take backup before edit